# gt Tables - applying formatting to multiple dataframes

Tags: r, function, gt

I have several tables that all need to be formatted similarly. I figured out how I want the tables formatted on one table, and have been trying to write a function that I can apply to all tables easily without having to copy and paste the code over and over

Here is my sample data frame

```
example <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
               age = c("age 12 to 17", "age 18 to 25", "age 26 and up"),
           alc_est = c(14579.28558, 131872.35964, 660957.6512),
          bing_alc = c(0.0477, 0.3143, 0.224),
          marj_est = c(35913.3345, 137033.12968, 534667.52856),
            mj_use = c(0.1175, 0.3266, 0.1812),
        heroin_est = c(NA, 419.5748, 18294.36356),
        heroin_use = c(NA, 0.001, 0.0062),
          meth_est = c(550.16172, 2139.83148, 68161.25778),
          meth_use = c(0.0018, 0.0051, 0.0231)
)
```

Here is some of the formatting that will be applied to multiple tables

```
table_format <- example %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "age") %>%
  tab_stubhead(label = md("**Statewide**")) %>%
  tab_header(
  title = md("**table title here**"),
  subtitle = "more info here"
   ) %>%
  fmt_number(
      columns = c(2, 4, 6, 8),
      decimals = 0
      ) %>%
    tab_spanner_delim(
    delim = "_",
    columns = c(2:9)
)
```

Here is how I tried to write a function to apply to multiple tables. The function runs but doesn't actually format the table

```
format_use_est <- function(df_here) {
  result <-  df_here %>%
    gt(rowname_col = "age") %>%
  tab_stubhead(label = md("**Statewide**")) %>%
  tab_header(
    title = md("**table title here**"),
    subtitle = "more info here"
  ) %>%
    fmt_percent(
    columns = c(3, 5, 7, 9),
    decimals = 1
  ) %>%
    fmt_number(
      columns = c(2, 4, 6, 8),
      decimals = 0
      ) %>%
    tab_spanner_delim(
    delim = "_",
    columns = c(2:9)
      ) 
}
```

How can I write a function for formatting these tables and apply to multiple tables more effectively? Thank you!

Comment: There are some typos, in the function, `columns  = c(3, 5, 7,9),` a comma is missing,  also `return(result)` or you don't need to create the `result <-`.  then applying the function as `format_use_est(example)`  If there are more datasets, loop over them in a `list` and apply i.e. `purrr::walk(list(example, example), format_use_est)`

Comment: Or can be `map` `map(list(example, mtcars), format_use_est)`